# Creating a slider but having trouble fitting image in center of absolute div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am currently working on a project which is a mobile-first e-commerce responsive website. I am trying to create a sliding div of products detailing the top selling range.

The idea is to allow the user to click on either the left or right slide-arrows and the products range will slide accordingly - a feature Im sure you have probalby seen on on most e-commerce websites.

Right now I am on the design aspect of creating this section but for some reason I can not center the images which appear in the divs. Am i disributing the percentages correctly? I plan on showing one product image in the mobile version but 3 in the desktop version.

My code is shown below.

HTML:

```css
/* TOP SELLING RANGE SECTION */

    .mobile-topselling-slideshow {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
    }
    
    .top-selling-arrows {
     width: 10%;
     text-align: center;
     color: green;
     font-size: 2em;
    }
    
    #top-selling-slider {
     position: relative;
     width: 80%;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #top-selling-productdetails {
     z-index: 60000;
     display: flex;
     width: 600%;
    }
    
    .topseller-sliding-divs {
     width: 13.3%
    }
    
    
    .topseller-sliding-divs img {
     width: 100%;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="content-container">
    
    <section class="special-offers">
    
    <h1>THIS WEEK'S TOP SELLERS</h1>
    
    <div class="mobile-topselling-slideshow">
    
    <div id="left-scroll-topselling" class="top-selling-arrows">
    
    <i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="topselling-products">
    
    <div id="top-selling-slider">
    
    <div id="top-selling-productdetails">
    
    <div id="item1topseller" class="topseller-sliding-divs">
    <img src="images/sports/5.png" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="item2topseller" class="topseller-sliding-divs">
    <img src="images/sports/1.jpg" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="item3topseller" class="topseller-sliding-divs">
    <img src="images/sports/5.png" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="item4topseller" class="topseller-sliding-divs">
    <img src="images/sports/5.png" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="item5topseller" class="topseller-sliding-divs">
    <img src="images/sports/5.png" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="item6topseller" class="topseller-sliding-divs">
    <img src="images/sports/5.png" />
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="right-scroll-topselling" class="top-selling-arrows">
    
    <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
    
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    </section>
    
    </div>
```

An image of the outcome is also shown below

[image]

Comment: add `text-align:center` on `.topseller-sliding-divs`?  Although your images are 100% width so they should take up whole div?

Comment: Not working pete. I would have thought that setting the images width to 100% would fill up the div.

Comment: yes it should but then if it fills the div, how do you expect it to be centred if it is the full width - surely by default there will be no space either side, ergo it is already centred or are you trying to centre something else rather than the images?  Now if your question is how do I get the slide to be 100% width of the screen / slider, then you would need to show us more css and js and perhaps use some placeholder images in your [mcve]

Comment: I am trying to center the images within the divs. I have even tried setting the images width smaller and then giving margin auto but still no centering occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `display: flex;` then for aligning its content to center, you have to use `justify-content:center;` not `text-align: center;`
 Try this.

```css
 .special-offers h1{
   text-align: center;
 }
 .mobile-topselling-slideshow {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .top-selling-arrows {
     width: 10%;
     text-align: center;
     color: green;
     font-size: 2em;
    }
    
    #top-selling-slider {
     position: relative;
     width: 80%;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #top-selling-productdetails {
     z-index: 60000;
     display: flex;
     width: 600%;
    }
    
   .topseller-sliding-divs {
    width: 13.3%;
     text-align:center;
}
.topseller-sliding-divs img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
    
    <section class="special-offers">
    
    <h1>THIS WEEK'S TOP SELLERS</h1>
    
    <div class="mobile-topselling-slideshow">
    
    <div id="left-scroll-topselling" class="top-selling-arrows">
    
    <i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="topselling-products">
    
    <div id="top-selling-slider">
    
    <div id="top-selling-productdetails">
    
    <div id="item1topseller" class="topseller-sliding-divs">
    <img src="images/sports/5.png" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="item2topseller" class="topseller-sliding-divs">
    <img src="images/sports/1.jpg" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="item3topseller" class="topseller-sliding-divs">
    <img src="images/sports/5.png" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="item4topseller" class="topseller-sliding-divs">
    <img src="images/sports/5.png" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="item5topseller" class="topseller-sliding-divs">
    <img src="images/sports/5.png" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="item6topseller" class="topseller-sliding-divs">
    <img src="images/sports/5.png" />
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="right-scroll-topselling" class="top-selling-arrows">
    
    <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
    
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    </section>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try, replace these two classes with your code and check:

```
.topseller-sliding-divs {
    width: 13.3%;
    text-align: center;
}
.topseller-sliding-divs img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```